# What is angularfire's $value?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am just trying to get a value out of my firebase using angularjs and angularfire...having issues.

Inside my controller:

```
$scope.componentStatus = syncData("components/-JI_JgHxm0TEUEVjADJn/status");
console.log($scope.componentStatus);
```

This returns an object which has `$value` as one of the objects within it.

BUT, when I try:

```
console.log($scope.componentStatus.$value);
```

I get `Undefined` as the result.

Any pointers? I feel like this should be an easy task, so I'm just missing something.

**Versions Used**
https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js
Angularjs - 1.2.7
Angularfire - 0.6.0

**Data Structure**

```
components : {
    "-JI_dFtOxE5k1ZFeZu8a" : {
      "experience" : "-JJ8jT0oJA3vYOeBNpq5",
      "name" : "Name of Component",
      "status" : "-JJ8hQcUb0_ip9Hoqcqq",
      "theme" : "-JJ8mD9tEsBw3a3g9Wz6"
    },
}
```

Comment: `$value` is mentioned in the reference guide, https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html , in the section about the constructor.

Comment: @Mikke the docs are fine, but it doesn't explain why we get `undefined` as the result.

Comment: $value is only defined for primitives. Is status a primitive? The $firebase object itself contains keys for any child records (if it is an object). We need a bit more information about versions, data structure, and code to reproduce/verify this and really understand the question.

Comment: @Kato, thanks for replying. I updated the question with some more info. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple misunderstanding of asynchronous processes. At the time that you call `$value`, the data has not been fetched from the server yet.

Try calling this inside a $on('loaded', ...) callback:

```
$scope.componentStatus = syncData("components/-JI_JgHxm0TEUEVjADJn/status");
$scope.componentStatus.$on('loaded', function() {
    console.log($scope.componentStatus.$value);
});
```

Note that if what you're actually trying to do is display this in the DOM, there's no need to worry about when the data arrives--Firebase and Angular will work it out on their own:

```
<div>When it arrives, it will appear here: {{componentStatus.$value}}</div>
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating these concepts: 
http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/e7WFf/

And another showing the same idea with $bind:
http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/4J356/

As of angularFire 0.8.0, you will also be able to treat the `$firebase` object as a promise with something similar to this:

```
var data = syncData("components/-JI_JgHxm0TEUEVjADJn/status").then(function() {
    console.log(data.$value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Kato. That was definitely it. In my use case, I didn't need to just display the value, but then needed to throw it into a function to return another value. Either way, my hangup was the asynchronous concept. Cheers!

Comment: In that case there is probably no reason to assign it to a scope variable. You can just refer to it locally with something like var componentStatus(). Also updated answer for 0.8.0